# HTML5 audio won't play on mobile devices (Android) even when it has to be clicked to start

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I'm working on a soundboard project, and it's going pretty good, but I have one major problem: the audio refuses to play on Android devices (at least on Chrome for Android as well as the default "Internet Browser" that comes with the device).

I know that most mobile browsers require some sort of user interaction in order to play video or audio for various reasons. The problem is that the buttons on my webpage have to be pressed in order to play audio, but they still won't play on mobile.

Here's my code so far:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Soundboard</title>
<style>
    .button1 {
        position: relative;
        left: 0%;
        bottom: 0%;
    }

    .button2 {
        position: relative;
        left: 0%;
        right: 0%:
    }
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function playSound(el,soundfile) {
            var embed = document.getElementById("embed");
            if (!embed) {
                var embed = document.createElement("embed");
                    embed.id= "embed";
                    embed.setAttribute("src", soundfile);
                    embed.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
                el.appendChild(embed);
            } else {
                embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="button1" onclick="playSound(this, 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3');">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByReL7sTnZRBV1plTkFhRGltTzg" />
    </span>

    <span class="button2" onclick="playSound(this, 'https://www.freesound.org/data/previews/371/371062_4929134-lq.mp3');">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByReL7sTnZRBV1plTkFhRGltTzg" />
    </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have a slightly less annoying problem where when audio plays the image moves to the right slightly. This issue isn't too big of a deal, but if you guys know a way to fix it that would be cool, too.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me out!

Comment: You can use the Chrome Inspect tab to check if there are any errors on the console. just type "chrome://inspect/#devices" on your google chrome in your pc, them connect your mobile device and make sure that usb debugging is allowed, and you should be able to pop the chrome inspector for your mobile device

Comment: Why do you use `<embed>` element instead of `<audio>`?

Comment: @guest271314 because I'm not using the audio tag built into HTML5. I'm using a function that calls the audio and plays it and stops playing it if pressed again.